# Why are ambigrams practically non-existent as company image?

Tags: logo, branding, conceptualization, ambigram

The ambigrams have great visual appearance, some are very interesting, others not so much and of course not all would be good as corporate image.

[image: oysho]

There are with the same reading when rotating 180º and horizontal or vertical reflection:

[image: abba]

Sometime ago some brands of companies transformed into ambigrams like Samsung or Oreo were published on internet. Logically, not all names give the same result to be represented like that.

Very few companies admit it as a corporate image: DMC, New Man ... Not even young and recently created companies.

[image: newman]

Why?

1 - **Ambiguity**: the double reading leads to interpret a conceptually wrong ambiguity as a company image.

2 - **Ignorance**: the designer is unaware of its existence or did not think of it as a design possibility.

3 - **Informality**: can be interpreted with a playful sense and indicate lack of seriousness.

4 - **Gimmicky**: once played the visual game loses effect giving a sense of ephemerality.

5 - **Comfort** or practicality: it is much easier to choose a designed font.

6 - **Discard**: should be definitely excluded as a branding option.

As a practice, it is an excellent typographic exercise. Here my full name.

[image: ambi]

Comment: The Dutch bank Bunq has a real charming one.

Comment: I think your own example (while nice) exhibits the problem: Unless you are lucky and have naturally matching characters such as M-W, a-e, h-y, o-o, N-N in the right places, the ambigram looks more like a bunch of scribbles than like a text

Comment: You are right, mi example is more for fun, i will never use it as my personal logo.

Comment: 7. They are challenging to create :-)

Comment: To be honest, these are a bit gimmicky.  Logo design usually depends on what the client wants. If the client doesn't ask for one of these, then that's your answer.

Comment: [Sun Microsystems](https://www.google.com/search?q=sun+microsystems&client=firefox-b-1-ab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinx93M75bbAhVDtVMKHU_PAMgQ_AUICygC&biw=1027&bih=594) had a square that read "SUN" in four directions.

Comment: @Emilie actually.. there are apps for that `;)` https://www.flipscript.com/ambigram-generator.aspx

Comment: @Scott Horrible apps!

Comment: I make no representation regarding quality `:)`

Comment: My questions are always about quality design, the other stuff I do not even consider ;-)

Comment: @Scott let me rephrase that... Beautiful ambigrams can be challenging to create. Don't get me started about the apps!! :-)

Comment: I've wondered why Toyota hasn't done more with A TOYOTA; possibly they don't want people to think their products are the same coming and going.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I think that's a perfect example why it's not often done, since I've seen that logo many times before and never once realized that it actually said SUN....... It's a simple enough logo that it can stand on it's own, even if the reader doesn't get it.

Comment: See.. I always think "... un ... un ... un ... un ... un ... un ..." like a cartoon gobbling something, when I see the Sun logo `:)`

Answer (score 21):

Real world use is not that applicable.

Sure they are nice for the *designer's eye*... but in *most* use cases an ambigram is **less** clear and **less** defining than easy to read text/symbols.

Form vs Function.

If you can't immediately *read* what is being represented, then using an ambigram is *often* contrary to its overall purpose. In *many* instances ambigrams present more of a visual *puzzle* to the viewer, taking a moment to work out what is being represented (as in your spinning sample).

Therefore ambigrams, as a branding device, only really make sense if they are clear, well defined, and easily grasped.... which is rare.

Answer (score 18):

When talking about textmarks the reason is probably: Designers do not usually get to pick the name. Therefore the palindromic/mirror and or rotationally symmetric quality of the logo is up to chance. While you can manipulate the situation a bit, conditions leading to this kind of feature are quite rare. At least if you intend to avoid hard to read combinations.

Also being able to spot the possibility is also somewhat up to chance. Some people are naturally much better at spotting this spatial possibility.

And last but not least not all designers and/or clients see value in this. Sacrificing legibility to a gimmick is not necessarily  worth it.